# Page refreshes but details from contact form are not being sent to the email

Tags: php, email, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already uploaded my site to a test server and now am testing the contact form that looks like the image below:

[image]

I fill in all the details but for some reason I am not receiving the email. my code looks like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
    $to = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers optional/headers 
        $headers .= "From:$from";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 5) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap contact form with PHP example by BootstrapBay.com.">
    <meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
    <title>Bootstrap Contact Form With PHP Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1 class="page-header text-center">Contact Form Example</h1>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <?php echo $result; ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page refreshes but I do not receive the email.

Hope you can can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: missing  content-type header?

Comment: is your $body is right?

Answer (score 0):

> Always set content-type when sending HTML email

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

> check bellow code

```
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject ="Thank you";

$message = 'html code here';

// set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers optional/headers 
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

> send email with your updating code please check

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
    $to = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers optional/headers 
        $headers .= "From:$from";



    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 5) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: I just edited my question by adding the code you sent but I still do not receive the email

Comment: check updated code

Comment: You call mail function with wrong parameter mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: Do you mind sending an update with the entire php? sorry am just a bit confused

Comment: check my updated code with your updating code

Comment: Just edited exactly as you sent and it does not work. Is there any extra setting that I need to have perhaps?

Comment: you can get any error ?

Comment: No error at all. the page refreshes but when I check my inbox, nothiing

Comment: You can try with someone@gmail.com  you use $from = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
    $to = 'sidney@web2web.co.za';